# Django Ajax Multiple File Forms Redirecting to Json

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, forms

Everytime I submit the form, Django redirects me to a new page with the json data instead of staying on the current page. Confused as to what is wrong.

I am using Bootstrap and also had problems with inmemoryuploadedfiles that I was trying to serialize but not completely sure if that is the problem here. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var frm = $('#uploadForm');
    frm.submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: '{% url "replay-upload" %}',
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Success: " + data)
                $("#dangerAlert").style.visibility = "hidden";
                $("#successAlert").style.visibility = "visible";
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("Failed: " + data)
                $("#successAlert").style.visibility = "hidden";
                $("#dangerAlert").style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<form id="uploadForm" action='.' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group font-weight-bold h5">
            {{ form.replay_file | as_crispy_field }}
            <!--<label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose Replay File...</label>-->
        </div>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="Upload">
    </form>
    <div id="successAlert" class="alert alert-success" style="visibility: hidden">
        <strong>Success!</strong> You uploaded your replays
    </div>
    <div id="dangerAlert" class="alert alert-danger" style="visibility:hidden;">
        <strong>Danger!</strong> Your upload failed. Please check that you uploaded a proper replay
    </div>
```

Views.py

```
class FileFieldView(FormView):
form_class = FileFieldForm
template_name = 'PlayerMatch/replay_file_upload.html'

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    files = request.FILES.getlist('replay_file')
    requestFiles = {}
    requestResponse = []
    if request.POST.get('process_btn'):
        selenium_process_replay()

    if form.is_valid():
        for f in files:
            # Verify Correct Files
            if f.name.endswith('.SC2Replay'):
                print(f.name)
                requestResponse.append(f.name)
                process_uploaded_replay(f.file)
        requestFiles['data'] = requestResponse
        return JsonResponse(requestFiles)

    return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Comment: Have you added jQuery script to your HTML file?

Comment: yes I did add it